# Route error in rest api using dingo pakckage in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5, dingo-api

I am creating a restful api using laravel dingo package.When i am giving url localhost:8000/hello.it is showing error NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Here is my route.php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');

Route::get('/', function () {
  return view('welcome');
});

$api->version('v1', function($api) {
$api->get('hello', function(){
     return "Hello";
});

   });
```

Here is my api.php code.
I have set my api.php

```
'transformer' => env('API_TRANSFORMER', Dingo\Api\Transformer\Adapter\Fractal::class),

'formats' => [

    'json' => Dingo\Api\Http\Response\Format\Json::class,

],

'domain' => env('API_DOMAIN', 'api.restapi.com'),
'name' => env('API_NAME', 'rest api'),
   'version' => env('API_VERSION', 'v1'),
```

After giving route it is showing error.i have tried in every possible 
  way.please help me out. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have prefix `API_PREFIX` set then the route you've added corresponds to

`https://localhost:8000/api/v1/hello`

Assuming the prefix is `api`

If no prefix is set then it's

`https://localhost:8000/v1/hello`

Comment: Thanks for this. it is working but showing some unknown error.some thing 
"message":"404 Not Found","status_code":404,"debug" showing.

Comment: @pallavimishra you mark this as your answer if it works.